# Understanding DeprecationWarning errors when performing conditional indexing on a NumPy array (version 1.11.13, Python 2.7)

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

I don't understand Deprecation Warning errors when performing conditional indexing on Numpy arrays and would appreciate some clarification, hoping that it will also benefit to the community. Let's consider a NumPy array called 'block', containing integers from 1 to 12:

```
block = np.arange(1,13)
```

I can select values that are different than 4 by doing:

```
selection = block[block != 4]
```

Now I want to select values that are different than 1, 4 and 7. If I do:

```
selection = block[block != np.array([1, 4, 7])]
```

I get the following error:

```
__main__:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise != comparison failed; this will 
raise an error in the future.
__main__:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a boolean instead of an integer 
will result in an error in the future
```

Could anyone explain the reason of this warning, and specify the correct way to do this slicing (ideally, the proposed solution should also be applicable when attempting to extract values from a large numpy array that are different from values in another large numpy array)?
Note that select = 2 after the warning, which I don't understand either.

Comment: FYI: The first warning is not related to indexing.  It is generated by the expression `block != np.array([1, 4, 7])`, and you would get the warning even if that expression was not being used as an index.  You should take a look at the value of that expression--it is probably not what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code for what you're doing is:

```
selection = block[~np.isin(block, [1, 4, 7])]
```